# Data sorting and dropping duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame

df1

```
   ec  em  p_x  p_y
0 22  aa   44    45
1 22  aa   45    44
2 22  aa   47    nan
3 67  bb   56    92
4 67  bb   92    56
5 67  bb   92    40
6 67  bb   92    56
7 82  tt   23    12
8 82  tt   23    23
9 82  tt   12    23
```

I am looking for output as

```
   ec  em  p_x  p_y
0 22  aa   47    nan
1 67  bb   92   40
2 67  bb   92   56
```

I want to drop duplicated value based on column p_x and p_y for particular ec and em column. Please let me know how can i achieve this.

Or even if i can re order the df1 like

```
   ec  em  p_x  p_y
0 22  aa   44    44
1 22  aa   45    45
2 22  aa   47    nan
3 67  bb   56    56
4 67  bb   92    92
5 67  bb   92    40
6 67  bb   92    56
7 82  tt   23    23
8 82  tt   23    23
9 82  tt   12    12
```

I can use df1[~df1['p_x']==df1['p_y']]
And achieve the desire results

Comment: Can you explain your expected output?

Comment: You are going to have to explain more about what exactly you mean by "duplicate" because your intended output has many duplicates in it.

Comment: Why doesn't your output contain 82 tt 23 12 and 82 tt 23 23? They are the unique values of p_y for the maximal p_x for another pair of ec and em.

Comment: I want to drop duplicated value.I tried using
df2 = df1[~(df1['p_x'] == df1['p_y'])]

But this does not work as the sorting/ order  of column p_x and p_y are different.

Comment: I had answered but Im also confused. Shouldn't `df.loc[~df[['p_x', 'p_y']].agg(frozenset,1).duplicated(keep=False)]` suffice?

Comment: @Rup for 82, tt there is no change in p_x and p_y column p_x has 23 23 12 and p_y has 12 23 23. Though the order/index is different but there is no change in value

Comment: @Rup for 82 tt .. there is no change in the value for p_x and p_y column 
p_x has 23 23 12
p_y has 12 23 23
Though the order is different but there is no change in value.
I only want to capture the change for column ec and em if the value is unique/ changed in p_x and p_y column irrespective of the    order

Comment: @Vaishali i want to capture the change for column ec and em based on unique values in column p_x and p_y. Irrespective of order.  So suppose for 82 tt the p_x value are 23 23 12 
p_y value are 12 23 23.
It is not unique. Though the order is changing but the value are same.. so i want this 82 tt dropped in the output

Comment: What happens with longer chains? I assume 01 02, 02 03 and 03 01 will all cancel each other out because they're just 01 02 03 in different orders. But if we had 01 02, 02 03, 04 01 then both sides have 01 and 02 but without breaking rows I don't think there's anything you can remove. Is that right? Could you write down your logic as an algorithm please? Or is that the problem: you're not sure how to express this as an algorithm?

Comment: @RyanSchaefer my output can have duplicated value in column ec and em but not in p_x and p_y column. I just want  ec and em in final output which has unique/changed value of  p_x and p_y column.
For eg. 
82 tt the p_x value is 23 23 12 and p_y value is 12 23 23.
Though the order is different but the value are same for 82 tt . So i want this to be dropped

Comment: @RafaelC thankyou for the solution. This worked for me. But after doing this there are still some duplicate values left in the dataframe. So i use df[~(df[p_x ]== df[p_y ])]. 
I achieve desired results 99%.
But still  if p_x  is (22 e47)
And p_y  is (22 nan)
I get 3 rows with values as 22 e47 22 and 22 nan nan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the pandas code for your problem :

```
import numpy as np

conditions = [
    (df['p_x'].isna() == False) & (df['p_y'].isna() == False),
    (df['p_x'].isna() == False) & (df['p_y'].isna() == True),
    (df['p_x'].isna() == True) & (df['p_y'].isna() == False)
]
choices = [df['p_x'] * df['p_y'], df['p_x'], df['p_y']]
df['flag'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='black')
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=["flag"], keep = False).drop(columns = ["flag"])
```

let me know if this helps you

Comment: Thanks Ankit for the solution... this worked for me with numeric value.
But when i use the same code were p_x and p_y column has alphanumeric  value  it gives error related to string.

Comment: There is a change in general solution I will update the same tomorrow.